# Dismiss UIViewController after presenting another one

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I'm developing a single view iOS 5.0+ app and I'm going to navigate throw my ViewControllers this way:

```
SearchViewController* search =
[[SearchViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SearchViewController"
                                       bundle:nil];
[self presentViewController:search
                   animated:NO
                 completion:nil];
```

My question is, if I'm opening `SearchViewController` from `HomeViewController`, is `HomeViewController` dismissed after `SearchViewController` is shown?

I have a lot of `UIViewController`s and I don't know if all of them will be on memory while user is navigating between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If You want to Present Only one Viewcontroller you can try like,

```
 SearchViewController* search =
    [[SearchViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SearchViewController"
                                           bundle:nil];


    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
        [self presentViewController:search
                           animated:NO
                         completion:nil];
    }];
```

Answer (score 1):

When you present a `ViewController` from another `ViewController`, they never get released from memory. To release them from memory you need to explicitly dismiss them.

> The method `presentViewController:animated:completion:` sets the
>   presentedViewController property to the specified view controller,
>   resizes that view controller’s view and then adds the view to the view
>   hierarchy.

So you see you are getting a stack of ViewControllers and adding a View on top of another.